# Confirming the reliability of the string to be used in REGEXEXTRACT

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say the link models that I want to extract the values from, follow these two models:

```
https://int.testlinks.com/national/brazil/brasileiro/u20aab/20202021/s19803/final-stages/
https://int.testlinks.com/national/france/super-cup/20202021/uniquestages/s274/
```

Wanting to collect such values:

```
/s19803/
/s274/
```

1. The value will always be between two bars.
2. The value will always be a only once letter after the first slash.
3. The value after the letter will have numbers that can be `1`, `2`, `3`, `100`, `2500`, to infinity.

The string `"/([a-z]\d{1,})/"` is it correct and is it reliable?

The complete formula:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR("/"&REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "/([a-z]\d{1,})/")&"/"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&"/", "(\/[a-z]\d{1,}\/)")))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain to me the usefulness of ```&"/"```? Because without him and leaving only ```A1:A```, both are delivering the same result (correct result, by the way).

Comment: @BrondbyIF the idea is to get always enclosed output with / even when your for example f1234 is on the end and there is no ending /